# Exibir comentario na tela e apos um determinado tempo ser apagado JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, java, html, c#, json

Estou trabalhando com um codigo onde os funcionarios da empresa vão fazer os comentarios diarios que vao ficar salvo no banco de dados, os funcionarios podem fazer os comentarios em qualquer hora do dia, o codigo ja esta salvando normalmente no banco.

Eu precisava que apos ele salvasse o comentario o mesmo ficasse na tela e que nao possa ser alterado apos salvar mesmo atualizando a pagina e que ele nao salve mais no banco se ja tiver algo escrito ate dar 22h da noite e as 22h ele limpasse todos os comentarios.

```
///CODIGO .JS///

var usuarios = []

$(document).ready(function () {
    getusuarios();
})

///AQUI ELE CHAMA OS USUARIOS QUE ESTAO NO BANCO DE DADOS PARA QUE ELE MOSTRE CADA CAIXINHA DO SEU DONO REFERENTE/// 

function getusuarios() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:58035/Home/GetUsers",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        accept: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            usuarios = data;
            usuarios.forEach(function (usuario, i) {
                if ($('#minhadiv01 > .col').length % 4 === 0) {
                    $('#minhadiv01').append('<div class="w-100"></div>');
                }
                let div01 = `
                    <div class="col caixa-usuario"> 
                    <div class="bloco d-flex flex-column ">
                    <input hidden class="id" id="id_${usuario.Id}" value= "${usuario.Id}">
                    <input style="height:30px" type="text" class="textbox" readonly value="${usuario.Name}"> 
                    <textarea class="caixa-texto" id="txt_${usuario.Id}" ></textarea>
                    </div>
                    </div>`;
                $('#minhadiv01').append(div01);
            })
        }
    });
}


///AQUI ELE SALVA OS COMENTARIOS NO BANCO///

$(document).on('click', '#btnSalvarTudo',function () {
    usuarios.forEach((user, i) => {
        let userComment = document.getElementById(`txt_${user.Id}`).value
        salvarComentario(user.Name, userComment, user.Id);
    })
})

function salvarComentario(usuario, comentario, id) {
    var data = {
        UserId: id,
        Comment: comentario,
        Date: new Date().toISOString()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:58035/home/SalvarComentarios",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify([data]),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (response) {
            
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Erro ao salvar o comentário. Por favor, tente novamente.");
        }
    });
}


///AQUI É O CODIGO .CSHTML///
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "HOME";
}

<div class="jumbotron"></div>
<main>
    <div class="comentarios">
     <br />
        <div class="">
            <div class="row align-items-start" id="minhadiv01">

            </div>

            <div class="row align-items-end">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="bloco d-flex flex-column">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

 <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="width:100%" type="button" id="btnSalvarTudo">SALVAR</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Basicamente pra trabalhar com tempo pode ser [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) ou [setTimeInteraal](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) respectivamente um executa uma unica vez e o outro executa em um determinado tempo em loop! até você parar! então você abre a mensagem e use o `settimeout` para ficar um tempo e ocultar essa div!

Answer (score -2):

você pode pode fazer uma comparação usando o construtor new Date()

```
const date = new Date()
const horas = date.getHours

if (horas === 22) {
// aqui passa o script para limpar 
}
```

quando for true você passa o script que irar limpar a tela